# Is there a deb package to install Firefox ESR?

Tags: apt, firefox

I would like to have [Firefox ESR version](http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/) on my system but I would like to install it via apt-get. Is there a special package to install this?

Download link would be: http://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/all.html#en-US

Comment: I filed a bug request: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976523

Answer (score 7):

It has a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~team-esr/+archive/firefox-esr), but it is not launched yet, so we have to install it manually:

I suppose that you have a 32bit edition on Ubuntu, and you are using English language:

- Let's download it:

  ```
  wget ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/10.0.2esr/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-10.0.2esr.tar.bz2
  ```
- We will extract it to `/opt`:

  ```
  sudo tar -xvjf firefox-10.0.2.tar.bz2 -C /opt
  ```
- Let's move away the normal Firefox link:

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox-old
  ```
- Linking the new Firefox:

  ```
  sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
  ```

That's it. Enjoy!

**Note:** if you want to upgrade afterwards, launch it with `gksudo firefox`, and choose `Help > About Firefox` menu, and see if any updates are available. If yes, apply them.

Comment: Worthy answer but I'd not run Firefox using `gksudo` - it may not be safe for the files in the personal profile. There exist another way to update the browser. It may be harder, but it runs with stopped Forefox and it will change files only in the folder where Firefox was installed. It is described here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Manually_Installing_a_MAR_file

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu Trusty and Xenial exists new 
[Jonathon F's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-esr).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/firefox-esr
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

---

It maybe very useful because of new Firefox add-on policy.
I have installed 10 add-ons and 9 of them are marked as [LEGACY](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-add-technology-modernizing).

Comment: Debian has firefox-esr package, but Ubuntu does not. You may want to vote for it on [LaunchPad bug 1676164](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1676164).

Answer (score 4):

There is a semi-official ppa now, I suggest to use this.
There is also a description how to add and get it automatically update.

https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: `echo -e 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu focal main \ndeb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu focal main ' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt update && apt install firefox-esr`

Answer (score 0):

I would actually try Icecat.....

You can still keep Firefox Quantum and add Icecat

https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuzilla/

- Download the latest (52.6 now)
- Open terminal and type `sudo file-roller`, (enter password)
- Open and extract the file to `usr/lib`
- Go to main menu, (if you don't have it, you will need to install it) under internet, click on the add new item.
- You will find command and file at `usr/lib/icecat`
- look for icecat .....

  ```
  type of file = Program (application/x-executable)
  ```
- Icons are in the browser file.

Save it and your're ready

Done