# How do I install Firefox ESR from a command line?

Tags: software-installation, updates, firefox

How do I install [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/faq/) from a command line?

Mozilla is releasing a new major version of Firefox [every six weeks](https://arstechnica.com/business/2012/01/firefox-extended-support-will-mitigate-rapid-release-challenges/). With each release, there's a possibility of bugs, unwelcome new features and interface changes (as well as bugfixes, welcome new features and interface changes; of course)

For those of us who don't have the time and effort to cope with change on a six-week cycle, yet still need security updates from the newer versions, Mozilla is maintaining [Extended Support Release](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/01/10/delivering-a-mozilla-firefox-extended-support-release/) (ESR) versions, which have major updates approximately every eight *rapid* (non-ESR) releases, yet still receive security fixes.

How do I install the latest ESR release of Mozilla Firefox, and stay on the ESR channel, so that I will only get major update to a new ESR version?

I need a robust command-line solution that can be automated. Currently I'm installing Firefox with

```
sudo apt-get install firefox -y
```

Comment: Try putting the '-y' before the package name.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then put it before 'install'

Comment: @Daniel I don't think that is going to solve my original problem, i.e. install an ESR release. The regular Firefox installs just fine.

Comment: I see.  Got me there.

Comment: Answer is here: [is there a deb package to install firefox ESR?](http://askubuntu.com/a/305203)