# Problem installing older version of Firefox

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install an older version of firefox 57.0.4
I managed this successfully but FF auto updates me to v 59 which is terrible. I found a deb package and ran that and now FF no longer works at all. If I try any of the Mozilla sites for an older version I will always get 59 and there is no place to stop the auto upgrade. Very annoying. I'm now using chrome but would prefer FF.

Comment: This is a very bad idea for security and since your browser touches any internet site you go to see this for example of one such security update that would not be patched in firefox 57. https://usn.ubuntu.com/3552-1/

Answer (score 1):

Download Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR, version 52) for Linux from the [official Mozilla website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/), and install it alongside the default Firefox that comes with Ubuntu by following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305199/is-there-a-deb-package-to-install-firefox-esr/305203#305203). Then you can update the default Firefox as usual while Firefox ESR remains at version 52.