# Looking for reference for this site https://pkgs.org/

Tags: package-management, firefox, dpkg

I need to install FF 60.8.0esr, found a deb package on this [site](https://pkgs.org/), but does not know how reliable is the site, anyone has used packages on this site and can give me feedback, please.

Comment: Why don't you use the "normal" way via [mozillateam ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) ? [See this](https://askubuntu.com/a/963984/631600).

Comment: You do not trust the site but why would you trust anyone here? Could be the owner of the site responding to you. Besides that: we need questions to be about Ubuntu not about a random website.

Comment: @pLumo, thanks, that's what I'm looking for, I thought through ppa you can only install current apps.

Comment: @Rinzwind, sorry if I gave a wrong impression, English is not my native language, it's not that I do not trust the site, I was surprised to see a site that offers a lot of packages and not mentioned very often, so I thought maybe there's something that I don't know. Actually the question is about Ubuntu, I just learned that with ppa you could also install old apps, as explained by pLomo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a deb package to install Firefox ESR?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305199/is-there-a-deb-package-to-install-firefox-esr) (see link to MozillaTeam PPA for Firefox ESR). The pkgs.org is great search engine, the packages are located in the repositories. It is up to you - trust or not to trust them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the site when I was new to Ubuntu and didn't know about [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com). I liked the interface of Ubuntu Packages. But I can say [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org) is also a reliable source of getting packages. I have seen that the website only hosts the webpage that includes the link from official source's pool, i.e., they use official mirror of packages. Like if you want MySQL, packages will be retrieved from [MySQL](https://repo.mysql.com), for Virtualbox from [Virtualbox Replository](https://download.virtualbox.org) and for packages in main, universe, multiverse and restricted, [Ubuntu archive](https://archive.ubuntu.com) is used.

Comment: Thanks Kulfy for your explanation.